# problem related to prime numbers

Tags: calculus

if $p$ and $q$ are prime find all of the answers of $p^2+3pq+q^2=5^t$ ?
please care I am not that professional in this part of math

Comment: what have you tried? "professional" or not, surely you're able to research and/or attempt the problem and gather some thoughts about it. If you include those attempts/thoughts into the post, then you're more likely to get better help.

Comment: A first thing that comes to mind is rewrite the expression as $(p+q)^2 = 5^t - pq$

Comment: thanks . I have to try more because of that I said I am not professional I am only 14 years old I started to study math for Olympiad so I have to try more and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $t\geq 2$. Then we get easily that $p^ 2-2pq+q^ 2=(p-q)^2$ is divisible by $5$, hence $p=q+5m$. Replacing, this gives $5q^2+25mq+25m^2=5^t$. Hence $5$ divide $q$, and $q=5$ As $p=5+5m$, $5$ divide $p$, hence $p=5$. The only solution is $(5,5)$.